# Affine Zariski topology is normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, separation-axioms

> Let $C,D$ be two **disjoint** Zariski-closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and let $f,g$ be polynomial functions on $C,D$ correspondingly. Then there is a polynomial function $h$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ that agrees with both $f$ and $g$.

This is equivalent to the existence of a polynomial function $h_D$ that is $0$ on $C$ and is $1$ on $D$, since then we can just take $gh_D+fh_C$.

Let's try to prove this:
We have $f \in A(C), g \in A(D)$ and $(1)=\mathbb{I}(\emptyset)=\mathbb{I}(C\cap D)= \sqrt{\mathbb{I}(C)+\mathbb{I}(D)}$, thus $\mathbb{I}(C)+\mathbb{I}(D)=(1)$ and by the chinese remainder theorem we have $A(C \cup D)=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\mathbb{I}(C)\cap \mathbb{I}(D)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{ \mathbb{I}(D)} \times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\mathbb{I}(C)}=A(C) \times A(D)$.

However, I'm not convinced as to whether this actually constitutes a proof. For each $(f,g)\in A(C) \times A(D)$ we look for a function $h \in A(C \cup D)$ that agrees with $f,g$, so is that isomorphism really helpful?

Comment: If $C$ is infinite, there is no polynomial that vanishes completely on $C$.

Comment: @M.Turgeon: of course there always  is a polynomial vanishing on $C$ ! Why do you believe  the opposite?

Comment: By looking at your argument, I see that you write $C\cap D=\emptyset$. If it is assumed (you do not say), what you say is correct and is just Chinese Remainder theorem, which you seem to use in your proof.

Comment: @Mohan is of course absolutely right! The point is that $I(C)$ and $I(D)$ are comaximal ideals  if $C$ and $D$ are disjoint.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you, I indeed forgot to write this in the assumptions. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @MTurgeon You may be thinking of the fact that a polynomial function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ that vanishes on an infinite set must be the zero polynomial.  But we are looking at polynomial functions $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$, where for $n\geq 2$ any non-constant polynomial vanishes on an infinite set.

Comment: (I still don't know how to use the CRT to prove the claim... The only form of CRT that I know of which is applicable here is the isomorphism of rings that is mentioned in the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you've established an isomorphism $A(C\cup D) \cong A(C)\times A(D)$, so you know how to produce a polynomial $h:C\cup D\to\mathbb{C}$ given polynomials $f:C\to\mathbb{C}$ and $g:D\to\mathbb{C}$.  Presumably the thing you're wondering is: is this $h$ actually an extension of $f$ and $g$?

To see that it is, you need to actually look at how the isomorphism is constructed.  You write:

$$\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\mathbb{I}(C)\cap \mathbb{I}(D)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{ \mathbb{I}(D)} \times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\mathbb{I}(C)}$$

An important aspect of CRT is that this is isomorphism is actually the natural map $h + \mathbb{I}(C)\cap \mathbb{I}(D) \mapsto (h+\mathbb{I}(C),h+\mathbb{I}(D))$.

So the $h$ we get from this isomorphism has to restrict to $f$ in the first component, and $g$ in the second component.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!